# .toggleclass / .addclass not working - activating a dropdown by adding class "open"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

on my webshop I want to activate the shopping cart dropdown when adding a product to the shopping cart. I tried this through .toggleClass and .addClass.

This is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 $(".add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
  $("header-icon.animate-dropdown.dropdown").toggleClass("open");
  }); 
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

This is my html of the dropdown menu (when it's collapsed):

```
<div class="header-icon animate-dropdown dropdown"> <a href="127.0.0.1/cart/" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
 <i class="ec ec-shopping-bag"></i> 
 <span class="cart-items-count count header-icon-counter">0</span>
 <span class="cart-items-total-price total-price">
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>0,00</span></span> 
 </a><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mini-cart"><li><div     class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
```

This is the html when the dropdown menu is active:

```
 <div class="header-icon animate-dropdown dropdown open"> <a href="127.0.0.1/cart/" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
 <i class="ec ec-shopping-bag"></i> 
 <span class="cart-items-count count header-icon-counter">0</span> 
 <span class="cart-items-total-price total-price">
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>0,00</span></span>      </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mini-cart">
 <li><div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
```

I tried a test through the Chrome Console only using the .toggleClass("open"), then the dropdown was activated. But the code together doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me why the script is not working?

Comment: Are you able to trigger an alert on add to cart action?

Comment: yes, if I place this script in the console it will give me an alert as soon as I hit the add to cart button. http://prntscr.com/odrqzx

Comment: In the html you provided there are not closing `ul`, `li`, and `div` tags. Are you closing your tags in your actual file?

Comment: Not in the console. Are you able to trigger an alert when your script is loaded on the web page? If not, try this inside document ready `$("body").on("click", ".add_to_cart_button", function(){
  alert("added");
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Okay lets do it :)
At the root of your theme, same level as `style.css`, if there is no `js` folder create one.
Inside this `js` folder, create an empty file and name it `my-js-file.js`.
THEN, in your **functions.php** file add the following :

```
/**
 * Enqueue my scripts.
 */
function my_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js-file', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/my-js-file.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/my-js-file.js' ) ), true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

FINALLY, in the new created file `my-js-file.js` add :

```
(function ($) {

    $(".add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
        $("header-icon.animate-dropdown.dropdown").toggleClass("open");
    }); 

})(jQuery);
```

This should work as expected unless your targeting the wrong element.
Here the target element is `$(".add_to_cart_button")`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $(".add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
    var dropDown = $("header-icon.animate-dropdown.dropdown");
    // if the droppable does not have class 'open' then add it
    if (!dropDown.hasClass('open')) {
      dropDown.addClass('open');
    }
    // if it does have class 'open' then we close it ( preferable )
    else {
      dropDown.removeClass('open');
    }
  }); 
});
```